# Add notification email address PayPal button to send receipt to

Tags: paypal, paypal-buttons

We have multiple buttons (for different services). We want to add an email address to a single button to send sale receipts to. (now it is only sent to the email address of the PayPal account)
Is this possible with advanced variables (or other way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These types of buttons are a deprecated legacy integration method, so you should be transitioning away from them regardless. But to answer your question:

---

First add and confirm new email(s) in the PayPal account, https://www.paypal.com/businessprofile/settings/email

Then create a new button and when creating it in the bottom of Step 1 change the email address.

If you were to create the button yourself (not hosted with the PayPal button generator) you would set the email address in the `business` parameter that identifies the account to receive the payment.

Comment: do you know if this will send the notification to both email addresses (principal and additional)?

Comment: It will send one. If you need more forward it or something.

Comment: it is possible that this only works for the "add to cart" button? (it is under shopping cart variables) https://developer.paypal.com/api/nvp-soap/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx-websitestandard-htmlvariables/

Comment: If you are asking about the `business` variable, that identifies the PayPal account that will receive the payment, and applies to all these legacy button types